# Filtering selected data from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to only return the data needed, but can't figure out a way to get only the data that is request. The issue I'm having is the table can have multiple records of the samething but one column is updated with different data.

Want I'm trying to do is get the latest entry return code along with the name, product, and a count of records by name and product.

same table:

```
ID | name | product | ordernum| return code
1    john    abc        14423     0
2    john    abc         14423    1
3    peter   ade        13324     1432
4    peter   abed       43554     1324
```

So the return information should look something like this.

```
id | name | product | ordernum | return code | count
2    john    abc       14423          1        2
4    peter   abed      43554       1324        2
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Why `Id` `1` and `2` for the resultset?

Comment: What defines: latest?  I'm assuming return codes could be LOWER but still be the "Latest"

Comment: @ siyual that was my mistake corrected the id's

Comment: the id sadly no date records..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowed function to get the result:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Id, Name, Product, OrderNum, [Return Code],
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name, Product Order By Id Desc) As RN,
            Count(*) Over (Partition By Name, Product) As Count
    From    YourTable
)
Select  Id, Name, Product, OrderNum, [Return Code], Count
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

Comment: this would only return one product name. What I'm trying to do is the name mach name and product name are the identifiers. so if the row has the same name but a different product number it will return two rows as well.                           So like 1 john abc 2323 1222                    and   2 john xyz 2433 2222 would show on the results

Comment: @CrazyITWannaBe If that is the case, why isn't `peter` `abe` in your expected resultset as well?  Or am I misinterpreting your expected result?

Comment: because I'm an idiot and was rushed putting this in... sorry

Comment: @CrazyITWannaBe It's cool - was just making sure I wasn't missing anything.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @siyal yup that'll work! thank you.. Now to add that to my list of things on to figure out what that actually does :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  this will return an id of 4 for Peter; I assume the "2" is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH
cte AS 
(
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, Name, COUNT(Name) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) AS [COUNT]
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Name
)
SELECT * 
FROM Table a
JOIN cte b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
    AND a.Name = b.Name
```

Comment: the [cte] return the [name] and the latest [id]

Comment: the [JOIN] matches the latest id with data from table